# Select/isolate in multimodel approach

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In API reference described methods to select/isolate objects (in condition that only one model is loaded in viewer):

```
- select(dbids,selectionType)
- isolate(node)/isolateById(dbids) // that is the difference?
```

I know select analog for multimodel:

```
viewer.impl.selector.setSelection([objectIds], model);
```

Questions are:

1. Is isolate analog for multimodel mode exists?
2. How can I select/isolate two objects from diffrenent models at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the recent version of the API the `viewer.impl.visibilityManager` is returning a `MultiModelVisibilityManager`, so you can pass a model as second argument:

```
MultiModelVisibilityManager.prototype.isolate = function (node, model)
```

Take a look in viewer3D.js (L#17825) to see available methods on that object.

As far as I know there is no way to select two objects from different models in a single call, you would just issue one select call for each model passing respective ids. I don't see a problem with that.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the `isolate`, you can do something like this(borrowed from the `Viewer3D.js`):

```
// Get selected elements from each loaded models
var selection = this.viewer.getAggregateSelection();
var allModels = this.viewer.impl.modelQueue().getModels().concat(); // shallow copy
// Isolate selected nodes. 
selection.forEach(function(singleRes){
    singleRes.model.visibilityManager.isolate(singleRes.selection);
    var indx = allModels.indexOf(singleRes.model);
    if (indx >= 0) {
        allModels.splice(indx, 1);
    }
});
// Hide nodes from all other models
while (allModels.length) {
    allModels.pop().visibilityManager.setAllVisibility(false);
}
this.viewer.clearSelection();
```

For the `select`, you need to pass corresponding model and dbIds to the `viewer.impl.selector.setSelection([dbIds], model);` and call `setSelection` for each set, such as below. It cannot be archived at once.

```
var selSet = [
    {
      selection: [1234, 5621],
      model: model1
    },
    {
      selection: [12, 758],
      model: model2
    },
];

selSet.forEach(funciton(sel) {
    viewer.impl.selector.setSelection(sel.selection, sel.model);
});
```

Comment: This code doesn't work, becourse selection is cleared in models that not equals to given model (Viewer3D.js - 18580 line). To get multi model selection I have to use "model.selector.setSelection(ids)" directly and trigger change event manually